# Cant get my database to seed ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having problems trying to get my database to seed with entity framework / code first. I'm a beginner at .NET and I've tried numerous of solutions but none of them worked for me.

What am I doing wrong? I'm posting the most relevant code... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SampleData.cs

```
    namespace seed2.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AirplaneDB>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AirplaneDB context)
        {
            var airplane = new List<Airplane>()
            {
                new Airplane { AirplaneId = 1, Make = "Great Planes"},
                new Airplane { AirplaneId = 2, Make = "Eflite"}
            };
            base.Seed(context);
        }

    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
<add name="AirplaneDB"
     connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|Airplanes.sdf"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

AirplaneDB.cs (Context)

```
public class AirplaneDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Airplane> Airplanes { get; set; }
}
```

Airplane.cs

```
public class Airplane
{
    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add this to the Application_Start() method of Global.asax.cs:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new seed2.Models.SampleData());
```

Make sure you are actually refreshing the view in the browser. Re-building the solution doesn't seed the database.

Finally, you should add `airplane.ForEach(x => context.Airplanes.Add(x));` and remove `base.Seed(context)` in your seed method.

Comment: Yea, i forgot to post that part. I do have that in my application start. System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new seed2.Models.SampleData());

Comment: I've refreshed the page plenty of times but still nothing... It's gotta be something silly at this point

Comment: Did you add the App_Data folder by going to Project > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_Data?

Comment: Try adding `airplane.ForEach(x => context.Items.Add(x));` and removing `base.Seed(context)`.

Comment: In Solution Exploder, click on the name of the project, then try again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12885/discussion-between-davidkennedy85-and-skeasor)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see you saving changes like context.SaveChanges() Please try adding this line after  base.Seed(context)

Comment: context.SaveChanges() doesn't do it either :-/

Comment: try with what @davidkennedy85 suggested like airplane.ForEach(a => context.Airplanes.Add(a)); and then call context.SaveChanges();